# java.lang.ClassDefNotFoundError at javax.activation.DataHandler

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, noclassdeffounderror

In my application i am displaying gmail message. I am getting subject and date but when trying to get content of the message , I got the following error.

```
07-06 16:27:26.078: E/AndroidRuntime(11726): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
07-06 16:27:26.078: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getDataHandler(IMAPMessage.java:599)
07-06 16:27:26.078: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1380)
```

Searched in google but did not get any solution.
Please help..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure you have imported all required classes from your library package?

Comment: If you have added any external libraries/jar, go to your Java build path , Order & Export them..

Answer (score 0):

Download activation.jar from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-135046.html and add it to your classpath.